# Python: defining a function inside another function

Tags: python, function, memory, immutability

I have a function that I define inside another function.

```
def foo():
    x = something
    def bar(list=[]):
        list.append(x)
        return x
    return bar
```

I have two questions:

1. As I return `bar` from `foo`, how does `bar` keep access to `x`? At this point, `x` is only known inside of `foo`, but when we exit `foo`, how will `bar` know what `x` is?
2. `bar` has a mutable default argument. When the returned function `bar` goes out of scope, is this argument, `list`, deleted from memory? It will grow and grow every time I call `bar`, and I want to make sure it is deleted when no longer used.

Comment: As for the first question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25023076/476

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bar` keeps access to `x` by creating a *closure*:

```
>>> def foo():
...     x = 42
...     def bar(list=[]):
...         list.append(x)
...         return x
...     return bar
...
>>> func = foo()
>>> func
<function foo.<locals>.bar at 0x7fcae19ac050>
>>> func.__closure__
(<cell at 0x7fcae1b19910: int object at 0x1080d99a0>,)
```

As for the default argument, you ask "When the returned function `bar` goes out of scope, is this argument, `list`, deleted from memory?".

Functions are *objects*. Objects don't go out of scope, scope is a property of *variables*. If your function object is no longer referenced, then like *any* other object, it is available for garbage collection. In CPython, this is *immediately* after a reference count reaches zero. The default values of function arguments are just stored as an attribute, like in any other object:

```
>>> func.__defaults__
([],)
>>>
```

So yes, all of this will be cleaned up like normal. If the function object is the only object that references it, then when the function object ceases to exist, the list's reference count reaches zero, and then it becomes available for garbage collection.

You can show this to yourself by defining a verbose finalizer and using that as a default value:

```
>>> class Bar:
...     def __del__(self):
...         print('goodbye from ', self)
...
>>> def foo():
...     def bar(x=Bar()):
...         x.baz = 42
...     return bar
...
>>> func = foo()
>>> func = foo()
goodbye from  <__main__.Bar object at 0x7fcae1b19950>
>>> func = foo()
goodbye from  <__main__.Bar object at 0x7fcae1b19910>
```