# Mergesort - How does Recursion know where to return and the state of the array/list before recursion was called? (Python)

Tags: python, function, recursion, return, mergesort

I've understood the basics of Recursion. I've understood functions like Fibonacci sequence and Factorial and how the value is returned to the called function.

I found this code for Mergesort and modified it with a bunch of print statements so I can understand the flow of the program. I'm sorry its long.

```
def mergeSort(alist):

    print("Splitting ", alist)

    if len(alist) > 1:

        mid = len(alist)//2

        lefthalf = alist[:mid]
        print("lefthalf created as a result of splitting", lefthalf)

        righthalf = alist[mid:]
        print("righthalf created as a result of splitting", righthalf)

        print("Calling mergesort on lefthalf")
        mergeSort(lefthalf)

        print("Calling mergesort on righthalf")
        mergeSort(righthalf)

        i=0
        j=0
        k=0

        print("Merging begins")
        print("lefthalf, righthalf is ", lefthalf, righthalf)

        while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):

            if lefthalf[i] < righthalf[j]:
                alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
                k=k+1

            else:
                alist[k]=righthalf[j]
                j=j+1
                k=k+1

        while i < len(lefthalf):

            alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j < len(righthalf):

            alist[k]=righthalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1

    else:
        print("Returning to the line after the calling function")
        return

alist = [5, 6, 7, 8, 0]
mergeSort(alist)
print(alist)
```

I've understood how the merge logic works. What I want to understand is, After it merges the left half and right half of the smallest sub-arrays, how does it remember where it left off?

The print statements generated by the above code is:

```
Splitting  [5, 6, 7, 8, 0]
lefthalf created as a result of splitting [5, 6]
righthalf created as a result of splitting [7, 8, 0]
Calling mergesort on lefthalf
Splitting  [5, 6]
lefthalf created as a result of splitting [5]
righthalf created as a result of splitting [6]
Calling mergesort on lefthalf
Splitting  [5]
Returning to the line after the calling function
Calling mergesort on righthalf
Splitting  [6]
Returning to the line after the calling function
Merging begins
lefthalf, righthalf is  [5] [6]
Calling mergesort on righthalf
Splitting  [7, 8, 0]
lefthalf created as a result of splitting [7]
righthalf created as a result of splitting [8, 0]
Calling mergesort on lefthalf
Splitting  [7]
Returning to the line after the calling function
Calling mergesort on righthalf
Splitting  [8, 0]
lefthalf created as a result of splitting [8]
righthalf created as a result of splitting [0]
Calling mergesort on lefthalf
Splitting  [8]
Returning to the line after the calling function
Calling mergesort on righthalf
Splitting  [0]
Returning to the line after the calling function
Merging begins
lefthalf, righthalf is  [8] [0]
Merging begins
lefthalf, righthalf is  [7] [0, 8]
Merging begins
lefthalf, righthalf is  [5, 6] [0, 7, 8]
[0, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

I want to understand from the above print statements, how it remembered to come back to

```
Calling mergesort on righthalf
Splitting  [7, 8, 0]
```

after it merged the `[5]` and `[6]` to `[5 6]`

It came to the end of the statements in the `if len(alist) > 1:` condition.
How did it know that 'I haven't splitting and merging the right half'? Can someone help me here?

For `factorial(n)` and `fib(n)`, it was pretty straightforward that a value was being returned to the calling function, and understand how `return n + calledfunction(n)` in the recursive case was being executed. But there is not return statement inside the if condition.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, me answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46589881/python-recursive-variables-referenced-or-copied/46590249#46590249) may help.

Comment: Yes. This is kind of what I wanted, wondering if someone could draw out the stack. I don't know if this is me expecting to be spoonfed but this felt hard to trace.

Comment: Yes, that probably would be a bit beyond the scope of Stack Overflow. A good tool for studying recursion would be [Python Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit). Play around with it for a little bit and see if it helps clear things up.

Comment: @ChristianDean I just copy pasted my code onto that.. My god. WHAT A TOOL! <3 THANK YOU SO MUCH! I NEVER HAVE TO VISIT STACKOVERFLOW for Recursion ever again!

Comment: I'm glad you found is useful, @Abhishek :-)

Comment: Post as answer, so I can resolve it?

Comment: I would @Abhishek, but I didn't really give an answer. I just posted a link, which is explicitly not an answer. Furthermore, answering a question such as yours as I previously stated is a bit out of the scope of Stack Overflow. Don't worry about, it's fine.

Comment: Alright, if you say so!

Answer (score 0):

Each function call create a new frame, which defines a local environment. It inherits the variables defined outside of it. But the variables defined in it can not overwrite those defined outside of it.

The righthalf you created inside `mergeSort([5, 6])`, which is `[6]`, is in a local frame created by function call of `mergeSort([5, 6])`. It will not overwrite the righthalf defined in the upper frame which is created by the function call of mergeSort(`[5, 6, 7, 8, 0]`). The righthalf in that upper frame is still `[7, 8, 0]`.

To understand this, simply consider variables with same name defined within a local function and outside of it

```
def frame_upper():
  a = 1
  def frame_local():
    a = 2
    print("This a is in local frame:", a)
  frame_local()
  print("This a is in upper frame:", a)

frame_upper()
# output:
# This a is in local frame: 2
# This a is in upper frame: 1
```

As you can see, after the `frame_local()` executed, `a` inside the upper frame is still `1`. The `a=2` defined in local frame is not known by the upper frame. This is the same as your list `[7, 8, 0]`. It existed in the upper frame and is always there, it will not be overwritten by your newly defined righthalf `[5, 6]` and `[6]`, which are in a local frame and a sub-local frame under that local frame.

After `mergeSort([5, 6])` returns its final result. The next statement within the upper frame (this frame is created by `mergeSort([5, 6, 7, 8, 0])`) is ready to execute, which is exactly `mergeSort([7, 8, 0])`. That is how it comes back to that point.