# Heap and stack in Python variable

Tags: python-3.x, python-internals

I know variable is just a tag to an object
example `num=10`,
**num** becomes tag/reference
**10** becomes the object stored in heap memory
where does **num** get stored?

Comment: [Feel free to browse the cpython source code if you're interested in looking into these things yourself](https://github.com/python/cpython). You might also get a better picture of how the memory management of your program works by playing around with [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) in a REPL.

Comment: Note that python makes no guarantees about memory layout. Are you asking about a specific implementation? Are you asking about the *name* num, the *reference* num or the *value of* num?

Comment: reference num in cpython. value of num i know is stored as an object in the heap. Is the reference num stored inside the stack?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have a stack/heap and how is memory managed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546178/does-python-have-a-stack-heap-and-how-is-memory-managed)

Answer (score 4):

Ultimately it's in heap memory too; either:

1. It's a global, in which case the name it ends up as a key in the `dict` containing the module globals, with the value storing the reference to the actual object, or
2. It's a local, in which case the "name" is described in the function metadata itself, and the reference to the value ends up in an array of local references stored in the frame object allocated on entering the function (and typically freed when the function returns, though closures and exception-triggered tracebacks can cause the frame to last beyond the lifetime of the function call itself). The actual bytecode doesn't really use the name, it's converted to the index into the array of locals for speed, but the same index can retrieve the name for debugging purposes from the function metadata.

Since `dict`s, functions, and frames are all heap allocated, the binding to the name is ultimately in heap allocated memory.

Comment: To be clear, I'm describing the CPython (the Python reference interpreter) implementation, which may not translate directly to other interpreters, e.g. the CPython concept of frames is not universal. The constraints of the language spec would lead to similar designs in other implementations though.