# Advantages of a VM

Tags: language-agnostic, operating-system, bytecode, jit, vm-implementation

The majority of languages I have come across utilise a VM, or virtual machine. Languages such as Java (the JVM), Python, Ruby, PHP (the HHVM), etc.

Then there are languages such as C, C++, Haskell, etc. which compile directly to native.

My question is, what is the advantage of using a VM (outside of OS-independence)? Isn't using a VM just creating an extra interpretation step, by going [source code -> bytecode -> native] instead of just [source code -> native]?

Why use a VM when you can compile directly?

*EDIT*

My understanding is that Python, Ruby, et al. use something akin to a VM, if not exactly fitting under such a definition, where scripts are compiled to an intermediate representation (for Python, e.g. .pyc files).

*EDIT 2*

Yep. Looked it up. Python, Ruby and PHP all use intermediate representations, but are simply not stored in seperate files but executed by the VM directly. See question : [Java "Virtual Machine" vs. Python "Interpreter" parlance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441824/java-virtual-machine-vs-python-interpreter-parlance)

> " Even though Python uses a virtual machine under the covers, from a
>   user's perspective, one can ignore this detail most of the time. "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An advantage of VM is that, it is much easier to modify some parts of the code on runtime, which is called [Reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29). It brings some elegance capabilities. For example, you can ask the user which function/class he want to call, and call the function/class by its STRING name.  In Java programs (and maybe some other VM-based languages) users can add additional library to the program *in runtime*, and the library can be run  immediately!

Another advantage is the ability to use  advanced garbage collection, because the bytecode's structure is easier to analyze.

Let me note that a virtual machine does not always interpret the code, and therefore it is not always slower than machine code. For example, Java has a component named *hotspot* which searches for code blocks that are frequently called, and replaces their bytecode with native code (machine code). For instance, if a `for` loop is called for, say , 100+ times, hotspot converts it to machine-code, so that in the next calls it will run natively! This insures that just the *bottlenecks* of your code are running natively, while the rest part allows for the above advantages.

*P.S.* It is not impossible to compile the code directly to native code. Many VM-based languages have compiler versions (e.g. there is a compiler for PHP: http://www.phpcompiler.org). However, remember that you are disabling some of the above features by compiling the whole program to native code.

*P.S.* The [source-code -> byte-code] part is not a problem, it is compiled once and does not relate to execution time. I presumed you are asking why they do not execute the machine code while it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Python, Ruby, and PhP do not utilize VMs. They are, however, interpreted.

To answer your actual question: Java utilizes a VM in order to add some distance between the operating system/hardware and the code being executed. The goal there was security and hardiness (hardiness meaning there was a lower likelihood of code having an averse effect on other processes in the system.)

All the languages you listed are interpreted so I think what you may have actually meant to ask was the difference between interpreted and compiled languages. Interpreted languages are cross-platform. That is the biggest, and main, advantage. You need not compile them for each different set of hardware or operating system they operate on, and instead they will simply work everywhere.

The advantage of a compiled language, traditionally, is speed and efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Because a VM allows for the same set of instructions to be run on my different operating systems (provided they have the interperetor)

Let's take Java as an example. Java gets compiled into bytecode, which is basically a set of operations for a computer to follow. However, not all processors in computers understand the same set of instructions the same way - meaning, what one set of native instruction means on computer A could be something different on computer B.

As a result, a VM is run, with one specific to each computer. This way, the Java bytecode that is written is standardized, and only the interpreter has to work to convert it to machine language.

Answer (score 0):

OS independence is a big part of it but you also get abstractions from other things like CPUs... the same Java code can execute on ARM, x86, whatever without modification so long as there is a JVM in place.