# How does python keep track of variable data types?

Tags: python

I am mostly familiar with Java and am in the process of learning Python. I have been playing around with OOP in Python and am slightly confused how it keeps track of data types. What I am confused about is the get_average_grade() function in the image below. In the for loop how does Python know that student is an object of type Student? Note: the list self.students was assigned to be an empty list in the class' **init**.

[Image related to question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy4JH.png)

Comment: Check out [How and when does Python determine the data type of a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53449112/how-and-when-does-python-determine-the-data-type-of-a-variable)

Comment: Please include any code as text in the question, not as an image.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Python is a dynamically typed language, the *type* of an object is determined at runtime, so a lot of stuff from a statically typed language like Java isn't going to translate directly. What *exactly* are you asking?

Comment: Python does not need to know that `student` is an object of type `Student`. See https://realpython.com/lessons/duck-typing/

Comment: It is very important to understand, in Python, *variables* don't have a data type. They can refer to *any* type of object

Comment: Helps to better understand the [Python Interpreter vs. JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441824/java-virtual-machine-vs-python-interpreter-parlance/1732383#1732383) to see why Python typing is so dynamic.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am wondering how Python knows that student (the iterator)  has access to the method get_grade() defined in the Student Class?

Comment: @Max it doesn't know, until it tries to execute that method.

Comment: @Max it doesn't "know". It tries to access that attribute and call the resulting object. Try passing something else, it will throw a runtime error. Note, in that isn't a *iterator*. But that's a semantic quibble

Comment: And note, it doesn't have to be a student object, it will accept any object, and will not throw an error for any object with a `get_grade()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python variables don't actually have data types. Python variables are simply symbolic names for a reference (or pointer) to an object. That object has a value (for example 23 or "cat") and a type (for example *str* or *int* or *Student*). A name can be associated with an *int* one second and with a *Student* the next second.

You can call `get_grade()` on *any* variable. If that variable doesn't have a `get_grade()` method then the result is an AttributeError exception.

Some helpful background that all Python programmers should read:

- [python variables](https://realpython.com/python-variables/)
- [duck typing](https://realpython.com/lessons/duck-typing/)
- [names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Python is smart enough to know what type you want a variable to be when you assign it. Check this out.

```
student = 'Hi Mom!'
print (student)

student = 7
print (student)

student = [1, 2, 3]
print (student)
```

At any time 'student' can be a string, integer, list, dictionary etc, etc...